# node sqlite3 lastID is not returning

Tags: node.js, electron

i am trying to return the **lastID** after Inserting Data Into an SQLite Table from a Electron.js Application. Although the data inserts into the table the LastID does not return

this the code in electrons main.js

```
   ipcMain.on('categories:add',(e,category)=>{
      try {
          Category.insert(
             category.name,
            category.description
          );
        } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
        }
    })
```

this is the code from category.js
import {db} from './db_connection'

```
 class Category{

   constructor(name,description){
    this.name = name,
    this.description = description
    
  }

  static createTable(){
    let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  categories(
        id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name    TEXT,
        description TEXT
    )`

    return db.run(sql)
}

static insert(name,description){
   db.run(` INSERT INTO categories VALUES(?,?,?) `,
            [this.lastID,name,description],(err)=>{
                if(err){
                    return console.log(err.message)
                }
                return console.log(this.lastID)
        })
}
```

}

How do i get the lastID as a response after insertion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like scoping issue of using arrow functions as callbacks. Using classic function fixed this issue for me, for example:

```
  db.run(`INSERT INTO categories VALUES(?,?,?) `,
           [this.lastID, name, description], function(err) {
               if (err) {
                   return console.log(err.message)
               }
               return console.log(this.lastID)
       })
}
```

I'm also unsure regarding `static` usage here, could be also interfering with `this`.